# How do i replace raise exception with return None

Tags: python, recursion

I do need help with changing the following function. The following function checks recursiv if an given integer can be sum from a given integer-list. I want to change it that it returns None instead of raising the exception error.

```
def sum_possible(nums, target):
    if not target:  # base case 0 -> empty list
        return []
    for i, num in enumerate(nums, 1):
        try:
            return [num] + sum_possible(nums[i:], target-num)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError("not possible")
```

Comment: Might be simplest to simply wrap the function, catching the exception in the wrapper, and returning `None` in that situation. The alternative would require inspecting the value of `sum_possible` every time it's called.

Comment: Just replace ```raise ValueError("not possible")```  with ```return None```. You can even just get rid of that line entirely, but that might be less clear in terms readability.

Comment: @saradartur if i replace `raise ValueError("not possible")`  with `return None` the programm doesnt return none and crashes instead if there is no sum possible ```return [num] + sum_possible(nums[i:], target-num)
  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list```

Comment: What do you mean it crashes, what is the error? Returning ```None``` instead of  raising error changes the behavior of the function so can cause errors elsewhere in your program.

Comment: @saradartur `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list` thats the error

Comment: @johnsc I apologize, I did not realize the function is recursive. Give me a second.

Comment: @johnsc check the answer.

Comment: You got more points for posting this code with a question than the person who [provided it to you as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65221624/5771269)!  Give credit where it's due.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def sum_possible(nums, target, nums_len):
    if not target:  # base case 0 -> empty list
        return []
    for i, num in enumerate(nums, 1):
        try:
            return [num] + sum_possible(nums[i:], target - num, nums_len)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            pass
    print(f"[nums] -- {nums}")
    print(f"[condition] -- {len(nums)} == {nums_len}")
    if len(nums) == nums_len:
        return None
    else:
        raise ValueError("[not possible]")

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
target = 200

possible = sum_possible(nums = nums, target = target, nums_len = len(nums))
print(possible)
```

Since the length of `nums` list is equal to its original length only at depth `0`, you know that once the condition `len(nums) == nums_len` is met the recursion is over and the `raise` statement will not get caught. Therefore you can `return None`. The original length of the `nums` list is stored in `nums_len` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the mechanism you consider to be *the problem* into *the solution* by encapsulating the orginal function:

```
def sum_possible(nums, target):

    def sum_possible_recursive(nums, target):
        if not target:  # base case 0 -> empty list
            return []
        for i, num in enumerate(nums, 1):
            try:
                return [num] + sum_possible_recursive(nums[i:], target-num)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        raise ValueError("not possible")

    try:
        return sum_possible_recursive(nums, target)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```